# Ошибка: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, словари, dict

не могу понять в чем проблема, string indices must be integers. Ссылка на [json](https://devman.org/media/filer_public/95/74/957441dc-78df-4c99-83b2-e93dfd13c2fa/bars.json)

```
 import json


def load_data():
    with open("bars.json") as json_file:
        json_string = json_file.read()
        parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)
    return parsed_string


def get_biggest_bar(data):
    biggest_bar = max(data,key=lambda x: x["SeatsCount"])
    return biggest_bar
```

JSON такой:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
    "features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                37.621587946152012,
                55.765366956608361
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties": {
            "DatasetId": 1796,
            "VersionNumber": 2,
            "ReleaseNumber": 2,
            "RowId": "20a0b7c9-dad3-4af8-a2a2-08170f74379b",
            "Attributes": {
                "global_id": 20660594,
                "Name": "Юнион Джек",
                "IsNetObject": "нет",
                "OperatingCompany": null,
                "AdmArea": "Центральный административный округ",
                "District": "Мещанский район",
                "Address": "Нижний Кисельный переулок, дом 3, строение 1",
                "PublicPhone": [
                    {
                        "PublicPhone": "(495) 621-19-63"
                    }
                ],
                "SeatsCount": 30,
                "SocialPrivileges": "нет"
            }
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: `x` — строка, поэтому `x["SeatsCount"]` не имеет смысла. Проверяйте, почему у вас в `data` оказывается список строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def load_data(filename, encoding='utf-8'):
    with open(filename, encoding=encoding) as json_file:
        return json.load(json_file)

data = load_data(r'D:\download\bars.json')

res = max(data['features'], key=lambda x: x['properties']['Attributes']['SeatsCount'])
```

результат:

```
In [42]: res
Out[42]:
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [37.638228501070095, 55.70111462948684],
  'type': 'Point'},
 'properties': {'DatasetId': 1796,
  'VersionNumber': 2,
  'ReleaseNumber': 2,
  'RowId': 'fbe6c340-4707-4d74-b7ca-2b84a23bf3a8',
  'Attributes': {'global_id': 169375059,
   'Name': 'Спорт бар «Красная машина»',
   'IsNetObject': 'нет',
   'OperatingCompany': None,
   'AdmArea': 'Южный административный округ',
   'District': 'Даниловский район',
   'Address': 'Автозаводская улица, дом 23, строение 1',
   'PublicPhone': [{'PublicPhone': '(905) 795-15-84'}],
   'SeatsCount': 450,
   'SocialPrivileges': 'нет'}},
 'type': 'Feature'}
```

Comment: Почему не `x['properties']['attributes'].get('SeatsCount', 0)`? Там же ещё вложенность.

Comment: Сейчас вы просто нашли первый элемент списка, потому что у всех был дефолтный  `0`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, действительно - спасибо! Сейчас исправлю ответ...

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, заработало:)